# Editing Spatial View in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, editing, oracle-dbms, spatial-view

Can spatial views be edited via ArcMap and, if it is possible, then how do I do it?

I do have my Enterprise Geodatabase on Oracle.